# Which PCI slots belong to which CPUs

Tags: linux, pci

I am running a quad-socket Intel Xeon E7-v2 system. I need to check to which CPUs chosen PCI devices are connected. Is there a way to do this on linux using e.g., lcpci/dmidecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lspci with the -t option to view in tree format, allowing you to visually trace devices to their upstream CPU:

```
$ lspci -t
```

Better yet, increase the verbosity so lspci outputs device names and details:

```
$ lspci -tv
```

Even more verbose:

```
$ lspci -tvv
```

Comment: I do not see any CPU-related structure in that tree.. It is a rather flat tree, I would say.

Comment: @angainor, Modern systems often have the majority of their pci devices directly connected to the processor(s), so rather flat is to be expected. Most or all devices will directly hang directly off of device number 00. If you add your motherboard model we can check into it further.

Comment: Do not use -t with lspci, just use -v, you will see which NUMA node your device is attached to which may be helpful